# Jenkins does not trigger build on downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins

I'm using latest Jenkins version on multiple Maven projects, sharing many dependencies in snapshot version. The trigger 'Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built' is enabled in all jobs and I can indeed see the correct dependency graph in the sections upstream and downsteam projects, but for some reason, when a build is completed on an upstream project, Jenkins does not trigger a build on all the downstream projects but only some. What can be this reason?
The option 'Block build when upstream project is building' is also enabled, in order to build projects in the correct order.
This used to work but it does not anymore. I'm wondering if it could be related to an error in determining the dependency graph for some projects, because of the complexity (circular dependencies?). But then, how explain that downstream and upstream projects displayed are correct?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is build dependencies as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, i should not have to configure explicitly dependencies in each job. Maven jobs are able to figure out what is the dependency graph, by analysing dependencies in pom.xml files. As i mentioned above, upstream and downstream projects are correctly displayed but for some reason, they are not executed automatically at the end of upstream build.